# Usage rate limit for FCM - 2500? or 400? for admin SDK

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Reading the docs I found:

> XMPP server throttling
> We limit the rate that you can connect to FCM XMPP servers to 400 connections per minute per project. This shouldn't be an issue for message delivery, but it is important for ensuring the stability of our system.
> For each project, FCM allows **2500 connections in parallel**.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#xmpp_throttling

Also within that page there was a description of different ways to connect to FCM to send messages. HTML and XMPP are different mechanisms, so I am assuming that the admin SDK (Golang in my case) uses HTTP under the hood and not XMPP so please correct me if that's not true.

If the admin SDK uses HTTP, that means there can only be 2500 simultaneous connections.

I'm making a scalable application where users basically define their own schedule for notifications (and the messages) and a server retrieves it, runs on a timer loop every 30 seconds or so to see who needs their message sent.

For all intents and purposes, each notification is different. However the vast majority of these notifications will land on the hour. Meaning my server will have to send possibly many thousands of notifications within the X:00 minute in the hour. It's important these notifications come on time (ie, I cannot space them all out within the hour).

Using workarounds like topics won't work in my case because everyone is individual.

I'm just thinking of options to deal with these limitations (and make sure I understand them). If FCM allows 2500 connections in parallel via the admin SDK in Go, can I do 2500 async connections, wait until they all finish, and do another 2500, rinse and repeat? That way if I have 25,000 subscribed users let's say, and each takes 1 seconds, I could theoretically send all the notifications in 10 seconds, which is acceptable.

Are there any other rate limits that I need to be aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am assuming that the admin SDK (Golang in my case) uses HTTP under the hood

That is correct. The Admin SDKs use the versioned HTTP API to make calls to FCM.

The key to scaling your FCM usage is to use the resources efficiently. For example in the versioned API (that the Admin SDKs use under the hood) you can pass up to 500 requests over a single HTTP connection, meaning that you can amortize the cost of building the connection over many calls.

You can find an example of the actual HTTP calls in the REST example in the documentation on [sending messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices):

> ```
> --subrequest_boundary
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
>
> POST /v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send
> Content-Type: application/json
> accept: application/json
>
> {
>  "message":{
>     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
>     "notification":{
>       "title":"FCM Message",
>       "body":"This is an FCM notification message!"
>     }
>  }
> }
>
> ...
>
> --subrequest_boundary
> Content-Type: application/http
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
>
> POST /v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send
> Content-Type: application/json
> accept: application/json
>
> {
>  "message":{
>     "token":"cR1rjyj4_Kc:APA91bGusqbypSuMdsh7jSNrW4nzsM...",
>     "notification":{
>       "title":"FCM Message",
>       "body":"This is an FCM notification message!"
>     }
>  }
> }
> --subrequest_boundary--
> ```

In the Go Admin SDK this'd be equivalent to calling [`sendAll`](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go@v3.13.0+incompatible/messaging#Client.SendAll), which:

> `func (c Client) SendAll(ctx context.Context, messages []*Message) (*BatchResponse, error)`
>
> SendAll sends the messages in the given array via Firebase Cloud Messaging.
>
> The messages array may contain up to 500 messages. SendAll employs batching to send the entire array of [messages] as a single RPC call. Compared to the `Send()` function, this is a significantly more efficient way to send multiple messages. The responses list obtained from the return value corresponds to the order of the input messages. An error from `SendAll` indicates a total failure -- i.e. none of the messages in the array could be sent. Partial failures are indicated by a `BatchResponse` return value.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I wonder as well, I was reading on another part of the docs that HTTP is synchronous, and only allows one connection between FCM and the server sending the REST request. If this is the case, if I wanted to send 10,000 messages, I'd have to do them in 20 x 500-wide batches synchronously (ie, wait for one to finish then do the next), correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what "HTTP is synchronous" means, but it's pretty common to open multiple connections to FCM and send messages on all.

Comment: "HTTP: Synchronous. App servers send messages as HTTP POST requests and wait for a response. This mechanism is synchronous and blocks the sender from sending another message until the response is received." - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choose

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that is correct anymore. But ether way: yup, it's pretty common to open multiple connections to the FCM send servers - and with 20-50 connections you should be able to push out  *a lot* of messages. If you run into throughput problems when implementing this, post a question with a [minimal repro of where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can probably help further.

Comment: This way of sending messages will be removed in 2024